# Shift position of click (X,Y)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to shift the position of a click  (X and Y) ?
I will be changing the cursor to a bigger image, and precisely, I want to change the position of a click without the user noticing it. For example, If I clicked position (0,0) on the DOM, I want the (0,128) area to be clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: "I will be changing the cursor to a bigger image" - how are you doing this?

Comment: The only way you should be changing the cursor to a custom image is with the CSS `cursor:;` property (instead of ugly hacks like absolutely positioning an element based on `mousemove` events), in which case the `cursor:` property lets you specify the "hotspot" in pixel coordinates, like in the linked QA I posted.

Comment: @Dai this works well enough, marking as an answer. Thanks!